# Webdriverio / Selenium - Basic Authentication with Safari

Tags: selenium, safari, appium, basic-authentication, webdriver-io

I have been running tests on a cloud service provider for Selenium and Appium called `LambdaTest` and I have been trying to run tests using `webdriverio`.

The company's sites all use Basic Auth, and that's not likely to change anytime soon. I am able to get by this with the old user/pass in URL trick, but it seems to be deprecated from support and already Safari seems to block it.

Is there any other way I can perform my tests and get past the Basic Authentication alert on browsers like Safari?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you try using the Apple's Keychain Manager ?
The authentication is stored in the Apple's Keychain for that particular website and you connect through it with Selenium.

It should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I don't run this on my own computer but on a cloud service provider (LambdaTest). I have no way of pre-configuring the browser like that, the code is automatically sent and executed on their Selenium Grid.

Comment: Ok. 
Can't you try to put the credentials to AWS Secret Manager then ?
And then, retrieve the credentials from the AWS Secret Manager, connect, retrieve the SessionID (if you have some) and add it to any request.

I used a virtual machine on Azure to do that. I'm sure you can have a VM on AWS and do this on that VM.